# Communication between Service and Activity on Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity

What are the ways to communicate between an Activity and a Service on android?

Today I learnt how to communicate by sending an Intent from Activity and replying back using BroadcastRecevier.

Which are my other options? Does anyone have a tutorial/reference regarding this?

Answer to this question is:

There are several way for an activity to communicate with an service and vice versa. This section dicusses the different ways and gives recommendation which to use.

5.1. Activity binding to local service
If the Service is started in the same process as the Activity, the Activity can directly bind to the service. This is a relatively simple and efficient way to communication.

5.2. Using receiver
You can also use dynamically registered receivers for the communication. For example your activity can dynamically register a receiver and the service sends outs corresponding events.

5.3. AIDL for services in a different process
To bind to a service which runs in a different process you need to use Inter Process Communication (IPC) as the data needs to be send between different processes. For this you need to create a AIDL file which looks similar to an Java interface but ends with the .aidl file extension and is only allowed to extend other AIDL files.

This approach is required if your service should be provided to other applications, otherwise you should prefer a local service.

5.4. Sending Intent data and bundle to the services
The service receives data from the starting Android component and can use this data.

5.5. Handler and Messenger
If the service should be communicating back to the activity it can receive an object of type Messenger via the Intent data it receives from the Activity. If the Messenger is bound to a Handler in the activity the service can send objects of type Message to the activity.

A Messenger is parcelable, which means it can be passed to another process and you can use this object to send Messages to the Handler in the activity.

Messenger provides also the method getBinder() which allows to pass a Messenger to the activity. The Activity can therefore send Messages to the service.

Thanks to http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Yes on google I'll search for learning the technique, on this site I'm searching for a tip from skilled people about topic to search! :)

Comment: wish you have the simplest tutorial of 
two communication (service <-> activity) in code. :D @user1959567

Answer (score 4):

Ways to connect Activity to  service:

1. Broadcasts: easiest way, implement a `BroadcastReciever` in each to listen to actions of others.
2. Messengers: Very good for multiple types of clients, Both service and client have a `Messenger` , service provides it Messenger in `onBind()`, clients sends a register/unregister message with its own messenger in `replyTo()` of message. Service saves client messenger. Now both can send/recieve messages.
3. IBinder: If you need full fledged remote IPC . Define an Interface for service with AIDL and pass Implementations to clients in `onBind()`.

Android [online reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) has explanations of each.

Answer (score -2):

The guys are right, you should really google for answers!

However, I recently learned a neat way to send intents to a service. You can simply call `startService(myIntent)` to send an intent to your service. If the service is not running, it will be started. If the service is running, you have the possibility to react on the new information.

Comment: you mean if the service is already running, 
and then somehow in the different activity I posted a new Intent to that Service using StartService() -> it won't break anything? I thought the Service is recreated.